# How get used plug-ins from an Eclipse ILaunchConfiguration

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an eclipse rcp plug-in the looks in the `manifest.mf` files of the plug-ins contributing to a specific `ILaunchConfiguration`.

I want to get the plug-ins from the `ILaunchConfiguration` and the `getMappedResources()` method returns null.

Any suggestions on how to get the contributing plug-ins? Afaik they are `IResources`

Many thanks.
P.S. Would've posted an image, but this is my first post.

Comment: What do you mean by `contributing plug-ins`?